# Is there a canonical date for the destruction of Romulus?

Tags: star-trek

All we know from the 2009 Star Trek film is the date when the star went supernova.  However, we aren't actually given the date for the destruction of Romulus, only that the "fastest ship" was outfitted for a mission to inject red matter and form the black hole to contain the explosion.  Was there an exact date for the actual destruction of the planet?

Comment: [2387](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/2387). I don't recall a *specific* date;

Comment: I am not immediately convinced of that, especially since Memory Alpha is not necessarily canon.  Is there another reference?  For instance, it is possible that the star went nova in 2387 (this for sure is stated in the film) but is many light years away, requiring a much longer transit time

Comment: The supernova in the Star Trek film travels at FTL speeds.

Comment: Perhaps yes, and I may be reading too much into it.  It's pure speculation at this point, but the reason I ask is that many articles say that Star Trek: Picard's "unthinkable" event is the destruction of Romulus.  I'm willing to accept that, but if the destruction takes place long after the supernova I'm not sure.  Perhaps it was instead the destruction of the Enterprise (hence why none of the other cast were asked to return).  With a more firm date I can put my suspicions to rest :-P

Comment: In the movie, old Spock says "One hundred twenty-nine years from now, a star will explode, and threaten to destroy the galaxy."

Comment: Also, the destruction of Romulus is shown on screen.

Comment: Yes but note that Spock only says a star explodes then. He does not say that Romulus is destroyed then. In fact since it isn't Romulus' home star that explodes the explosion should take years to get to Romulus itself, hence the question